# Having different columns and categories for each file level

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, metadata, file, choice-field

I have been tasked with reorganizing our SharePoint library using metadata filters. I was curious if it was possible to change what columns are present based on what file level I am in.

For example, we have a library where all groups involved on the project keep their documents. Under our group's portion of the library, we would like to be able to add a metadata requirement, so we can filter our documents, but do not want to force the other groups to add categories and metadata to their portion of the library.

Is it possible to restrict metadata by file level, and if so any suggestions?

(when I say columns I mean we are requiring a category selection for the "choice" style column).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create columns at file / folder level.

Columns can be created at document library level or content type level.

Possible solutions:

1. Create separate document libraries for different type of documents (teams/groups) to have different metadata / columns
2. Create separate content types for each team/group (inheriting document content type) >> add different columns to each content type as per your requirements >> add content types to same document library >> use custom content types to create documents.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, you could create different views with required columns for each group in a document library.